# How to set drop down value(s) of `select` box based on selected option in other `select` box

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, laravel

I Have two `<select>` boxes. Let's say the names are `selectdistrict` and `selectvillage`.

First, I need to get the value from select box `selectdistrict`, which is used to generate option value(s) for `selectvillage`.

I am new to Laravel. What must I do to get the value?

after I searched, I've found that it can be done using jQuery, using the `onChange` event to throw the value from view `selectdistrict` to controller and get it back to fill in `selectvillage`. However, I don't know how exactly to do that. Will someone please give me a hint/or how to with this case?

A. selectdistrict

```html
<select class="form-control" id="selectdistrict" name="selectdistrict" >
<option value="">-- SELECT --</option>
@foreach($district as $kota)
@if($item->district == $kota->municipality_name)
<option selected="selected" value="{{ $kota->municipality_name }}">{{ $kota->municipality_name }}</option>
@else
<option value="{{ $kota->municipality_name }}">{{ $kota->municipality_name }} 
</option>
@endif
@endforeach
</select>
```

B. selectvillage

```html
<select class="form-control" name="selectvillage" id="selectvillage">


</select>
```

The expected value option is sent from the controller, set to select box `selectvillage`.

[flow process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sp67S.jpg)

Comment: You need js to do that. I advise using VueJs

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO, There are many tutorials around and indeed examples on SO.  What have you tried?  It would be better for you if you could show some code which we could advise upon rather than ask ' how to do this'.  Post what you have attempted and you will get better quality responses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got the idea of how to do it. Here is the working example of that.

Run the AJAX call on the *district* change event. Get the list of villages related to the district from the database and append it to the *village* `select option`s.

```
$('#selectdistrict').on('change', function () {
  const districtName = $(this).val();
  if (districtName) {
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "/get-village-list?district_name="+districtName,
      success: (data, status, xhr) => {
        if (data) {
          $("#selectvillage").empty();
          $.each(res, (key, value) => {
            $("#selectvillage").append(
              '<option value="' + value.name + '">' + value.name + '</option>'
            );
          });
        } else {
          $("#selectvillage").empty();
        }
      }
    });
  } else {
    $("#selectvillage").empty();
  }
});
```

Comment: You don't strictly need jQuery for this. You can use native `document.querySelector()` and `.addEventListener()` methods

Comment: thanks you very much, you all give me hint, i already solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try these:

```
<select class="form-control" id="selectdistrict" name="selectdistrict" onchange="getVillage(this);">
     <option value="">-- SELECT --</option>
</select>

<select class="form-control" id="selectvillage" name="selectvillage">
     <option value="">--- SELECT ----</option>
</select>
```

In JavaScript:

```
function getVillage(event) 
{
    var district=$(event).val(); // has the selected district
    $.ajax({
      method: "post",
      url: '', //your url to get the village under selected district
      data: 
      {
         _token,
         district: district,
      },
      success: function(data) 
      {
          html = "<option>Select Village</option>";
          for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) 
          {
              html += "<option value="">**your village name here**</option>";
          }
          $('#selectvillage').html(html);
      }
      error:function(xhr,type,exception)
      { 
      }
   });
}
```

*Note:* You can also use the `get` method. In the case of the `get` method, append the district along with the URL and there's no need to use `_token`.

Answer (score 1):

When ever a district is changed you need to make an **Ajax call** to server in order to fetch its villages. In response you can show villages drop along div (I showed villages list with div id "dynamic_villages_list").

I assume you have two drop downs along with a `<div>` to show villages list returned from server. (create drop down for villages)

```
<select id="selectdistrict" name="selectdistrict" >
-- options---
</select>

<div id="dynamic_villages_list">
  <select name="selectvillage" id="selectvillage">
     <option>Select Village</option>  
  </select>
</div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#selectdistrict').on('change', function() {
    var district = $('selectdistrict').val();
    var ajax_url = 'Path to ajax call on server';
    $.ajax({
      type:"POST",
      url: ajax_url,
      data: {
        district : district
      },
      success: function(villagesList) {
        // add villages drop down to any <div>
        $('#dynamic_villages_list').html(villagesList);
      }
    });//ajax
  });// Change
});// Ready
```

So each time a district is changed, your call will fetch whole villages list from server and shows on your page. Remember to add jquery before making ajax call on your page.
Hope it helped.